# Problem with generating list in html template from array via *ngFor, Angular 9

Tags: angular, frontend, single-page-application

*ngFor doesn't display anything. Default cli's `<p>minimixes works!</p>` displays so it looks like the problem with ngFor.
Please look through my code:

**minimixes.component.ts** - displayed component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MINIMIXES } from './minimixes';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-minimixes',
  templateUrl: './minimixes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./minimixes.component.scss']
})
export class MinimixesComponent {
  minimixes = MINIMIXES;
}
```

**minimixes.interface.ts** - interface

```
export interface Minimix {
    name: string;
    coverSrc: string;
    soundcloudSrc: string;
    description: string;
}
```

**minimixes.ts** - here I store minimixes data

```
import { Minimix } from './minimixes.interface';

export const MINIMIXES: Minimix[] = [
    {name: 'name1', coverSrc: 'cover1', soundcloudSrc: 'src1', description: 'desc1'},
    {name: 'name2', coverSrc: 'cover2', soundcloudSrc: 'src2', description: 'desc2'}
];
```

**minimixes.component.html**

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let minimix of minimixes">
        <span>{{ minimix.name }}, {{ minimix.coverSrc }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But when I place just a text in this template, for example default cli's `<p>minimixes works!</p>` or any other content - everything is good. I also tried to import CommonModule but this did not solve the problem. I can't understand what the problem is. 
The compiler says that everything is good and browser console doesn't show any warnings or errors. 
Thanks, everyone!

Comment: I tried replicating your problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xw5vrf which seems working fine. Please check if you are missing any imports in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Is the `minimixes.component.ts` in the same directory as the `minimixes.ts` file? If it's one folder level in (for eg. `minimixes/minimixes.component.ts)` you need to include it using relative path `import { MINIMIXES } from '../minimixes';`.

Comment: try printing minimixes in your html and check whether it is printing any values by simply doing `<p> {{ minimixes | json}} </p> `

Comment: @MichaelD yep all files are in one folder but VS Code autocomplete path as `'./minimixes';` is it incorrect?

Comment: @ShijilNarayan thanks ill try it little bit later and report

Comment: If you say all files are in one folder, then `'./minimixes';` is correct.

Comment: you have commonmodule imported in your app module? can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @VladKolebaev: Here is a Stackblitz for your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tm2haw

Comment: @ShijilNarayan `{{ mixtapes | json }}` doesnt display anything too

Comment: @AakashGarg i tried import it in mixtapes parent module like `import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'` and in imports property of module like `imports: [CommonModule, ...],` but it didnt solve the problem, it was first thing i tried.

Comment: @MichaelD why did you import `FormsModule` in your stackblitz example??

Comment: @VladKolebaev, forms module is not required. its a default angular setup that stackblitz provide. but yea the code that Michael provided works fine.

Comment: I meant to print minimixes in your html <p> {{ minimixes | json}} </p>

Comment: @VladKolebaev: That is a default import in a Stackblitz project. If you have any doubts, you could directly modify it to see how it affects the compilation.

Comment: @MichaelD i just pushed project on GitHub. If you can please look through full code, problem components path is app/music/minimixes. https://github.com/sometimesvlad/meet_radio_show_spa

Comment: @MichaelD  I SOLVED IT I HAD ZONE JS TURNED OFF IN MY MAIN.TS HAHA!!!